# Maps and variable key names in Kotlinx-Serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

The `meta` is simple, but how do I model `analysis` for Kotlinx-Serialization?

```
{
  "meta": {
    "subject": "33306",
    "interval": "weekly"
  },
  "analysis": {
    "2021-07-20": {
      "dose": "0.6410"
    },
    "2021-07-16": {
      "dose": "0.9570"
    },
    "2021-07-09": {
      "dose": "0.6880"
    }
  }
}
```

I have this at the moment.

```
@Serializable
class Observation(
    @SerialName("meta")
    val meta: Meta,

    @SerialName("analysis")
    val analysis: Map<String, Map<String, String>>
)
```

But I get the error.

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Polymorphic serializer was not found for missing class discriminator ('null')
```

Comment: Serializer for `Map` is build-in in kotlinx.serialization library (see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/builtin-classes.md#maps), so the problem is unrelated to serialization of `Map`, it's caused by something else. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to model it as a `suspend` method in Retrofit and wrap its return type in `Response`.

```kotlin
@GET("/observation")
suspend fun getObservation(
    @Query("subject")
    subject: String
): Response<Observation>
```